# MIPS Assembly: INT to STRING function only 2 chars (cut off last char)

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I wrote this function to convert an int value to ascii string. But when the input is something like 315 it'll print 31 into the string.
As I'm not an expert in assembly any help with this will appreciate.
Here's the code: (int_buf is where the integer input is stored, $a is the string output)

```
 itoa:
  la      $t0, int_buf   # load buf
  add     $t0, $t0, 30   # seek the end
  sb      $0, 1($t0)     # null-terminated str
  li      $t1, '0'  
  sb      $t1, ($t0)     # init. with ascii 0
  li      $t3, 10        # preload 10
  beq     $t8, $0, iend  # end if 0
loop:
  div     $t8, $t3       # a /= 10
  mflo    $t8
  mfhi    $t4            # get remainder
  add     $t4, $t4, $t1  # convert to ASCII digit
  sb      $t4, ($t0)     # store it
  sub     $t0, $t0, 1    # dec. buf ptr
  bne     $t8, $0, loop  # if not zero, loop
  addi    $t0, $t0, 1    # adjust buf ptr
iend:
  move    $a1, $t0       # return the addr.
  jr      $ra            # of the string
```

EDIT:
I fount out the problem is not in the function, as it's in the way I print the string to a file afterwards:

```
li    $v0, 15
move  $a0, $s6      
move  $t8, $s2
jal   itoa
li    $a2, 4 //problem was only 2 digits selected here!
syscall
```

How can I prevent the tool from printing empty chars into my file when I set it to a default of 4 digits?

Comment: Looks like $t8 is the integer input, $a1 is the address of the output ASCII string.  Do you have a debugger where you can single step this code?

Comment: Yes, when at 'mflo    $t8' $t8 has a value of 27, which is the int value given to function in this case.

Comment: If the input is 27 (decimal) then at mflo (Move From LO, the quotient after division by 10, which is in $t3) register $t8 will still be 27... step one instruction (the mflo) and register $t8 should contain the quotient (2 decimal).

Comment: _"when the input is something like 315 it'll print 31 into the string"_ I'm unable to reproduce this with PCSpim. If I enter 315 I get 315 as the output. Please post a complete minimal example that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: When the function returns both $a1 and $t0 will have the address in memory of the string.  If the input is 315 decimal you should see 0x33 0x31 0x35 0x00 in consecutive bytes in memory at the address in $t0.  Those correspond to the ASCII values for '3', '1', '5', and the null terminator.

Comment: The problem is not in the function, as Michael said. Thank you both for your help :)

Comment: No problem.  If the syscall needs the number of bytes in $a2, then you shouldn't hard code it to 4.  Two options: (1) change itoa function so it puts the length in $a2 or (2)  compute the length after itoa returns.

Comment: Yeah but that's the point. How can I get the "length" of an integer value?

Comment: Well, in itoa function you know that $t0 points to the first valid character (byte) of the string and you know the string is right justified in a 32 byte buffer, int_buf.  So the length of the string is int_buf + 32 - $t0 (including the null terminator byte).

Answer (score 2):

> How can I prevent the tool from printing empty chars into my file when I set it to a default of 4 digits?

Calculating the number of digits in the string is easy. You know that the NUL-terminator characters is at `int_buf+31` because of how `itoa` is written. So just take the difference between that and the address you get back from `itoa`:

```
li $a2,int_buf+31
sub $a2,$a2,$a1  # a2 is now equal to the number of digits in the string
```

Comment: You could try using `la` instead of `li`. It works fine with `li` in PCSpim anyway.

Comment: That's probably why itoa did that in two steps (limitation of the assembler?)...   la      $t0, int_buf   # load buf
  add     $t0, $t0, 31   # point to null byte

Comment: @amdn should I use $t0 in li then?

Comment: The register you use should be of no importance, except that you have one of the operands in `$a1` (the address returned by `itoa`), and you presumably want the result in `$a2`. So it seems easiest to me to just use those two registers for this calculation.

Comment: @pike93, sorry for the confusion, like Michael said you can just use $a2

Comment: The problem is that I can't use a variable in li, because the then QtSpim gives me a syntax error.